# How do I make multiple celery workers run the same tasks?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I have one task that is checking a url speed, but i want that to be executed by multiple celery workers in different servers. I want the same url to be checked by multiple workers.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you could set `ignore_result=True` . Try [Broadcast](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/routing.html#broadcast)

If you couldn't, check [Routing Tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/routing.html#id2) and send the task multiple times to different queues, for different IDC for example, and corresponding workers.

Comment: I thought about sending the same task to multiple queues (one for each worker) but that didn't seem to be a really smart sollution. I'm going to see if broadcast works for me.

Comment: @gawry That's fine. just curious how do you collect speeds data to page.

Comment: i'm doing in a pretty naive way right now ( but I expect to improve it later ) - I just add a start_date = datetime.now() before calling the url and a end_date after calling the url